# VB.Net 2008 New keyword

Tags: vb.net

I could have sworn that I saw a quick demo of new features in VS 2008 which included a way to set public variables without creating numerous constructors that take variables and set them to values.  Does anyone know the syntax for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be talking about the Object Initializers like...this is a feature of C# 3.0 and VB.NET 9.

```
Dim cust = New Person() With {.Id = 2, .Name = "Jesse B"}
```

and in c#

```
var cust = new Person() { Id = 2, Name = "Jesse B"};
```

Comment: Note that in C# at least the () is unnecessary if you're calling a parameterless constructor.